# How to disable [Vue router warn] warnings in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

There are many warnings about routes in browser console. I want to disable them. How can I do it in `nuxt 3`?

(I mean warnings like `vue-router.js?v=09a4c81a:45 [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/list/item/2"`)